# Passing objects as *args tuple causes all instances of that class to be passed

Tags: python, oop, args

I'm learning python and started a card game to gain OOP experience. I simplified my  code below for demonstration purposes. It is showing behavior that I did not at all expect.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, things=[]):
        self.things = things
        for i in range(20):
            self.things += [Thing(i)]

    def move(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            arg.things += [self.things[0]]
            self.things = self.things[1:]

    def display(self):
        print('Room contents:')
        for thing in self.things:
            print(thing.num)

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class Box:
    def __init__(self, name, things=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.things = things

    def look_inside(self):
        print('Contents of box', self.name, ':')
        for thing in self.things:
            print(thing.num)
        print()

room = Room()

box1 = Box('Box 1')
box2 = Box('Box 2')
box3 = Box('Box 3')
box4 = Box('Box 4')

room.move(box1, box2)

box1.look_inside()
box2.look_inside()
box3.look_inside()
box4.look_inside()
```

> **Output:**
>
> Contents of box Box 1
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> Contents of box Box 2
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> Contents of box Box 3
>
> 0
>
> 1
>
> Contents of box Box 4
>
> 0
>
> 1

- The method *room.move(box1, box2)* seems to operate on box3 and box4 even though they aren't passed as arguments.
- I expected the method *room.move* would cycle through box1 and box2 as a tuple. So calling *room.move(box1, box2)* would move the first two *things*, one each into box1 and box2. But each time through the for loop seems to move a **copy** of the *thing* into each box (1 though 4).

Why does *room.move* affect box3 and box4 and how can I make it only operate on the Boxes I pass to it?

Why does the for loop in *room.move* perform the operation on all the Boxes instead of only the Box that is arg for that iteration through the loop?

When I look for information about how *args works, I can only find instruction about passing strings, integers, etc. I can't find anything that speaks to passing custom classes. I can only suspect that my problem is in understanding how this works. Can anybody recommend further reading or a tutorial on this specific case?

Thank you.